# Memory-Management in Qt: AddressBook tutorial

Tags: c++, qt, qwidget, qtgui, qdialog

So, I've learned so far, that Qt releases the memory of all child objects when a parent object gets deleted. Also, one generally doesn't have to care about memory management for objects created on the stack (i.e. NOT as pointers).

Now, when I did the very good ["AddressBook" tutorial](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/tutorials-addressbook.html), I found this in part 5:

```
AddressBook::AddressBook(QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent)
{
    dialog = new FindDialog;
}
```

Complete source is available:
[`addressbook.h`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtwidgets-tutorials-addressbook-part5-addressbook-h.html)
[`addressbook.cpp`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtwidgets-tutorials-addressbook-part5-addressbook-cpp.html)
[`finddialog.h`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtwidgets-tutorials-addressbook-part5-finddialog-h.html)

Here, `dialog` is a private member of `AddressBook`, and it is a pointer to a `FindDialog`. `FindDialog` inherits `QDialog`, but no `this`-Pointer is passed to the constructor (as seen above). No explicit destructor exists, there is no `delete dialog`-call...

Also, not passing `this` seems to be intentional:

> [The FindDialog's] constructor is defined to accept a parent QWidget, even though the dialog will be opened as a separate window.

Wouldn't this cause a memory leak? Or is there some other mechanism that will silently delete `dialog` and free its memory?

Thanks in advance for any help!

**Update:** I posted this issue to the [qt-project.org forums](http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/41686/) and it should get fixed soon.

Comment: Nice.  That is almost certainly a memory leak, unless there is some real magic happening with the `Q_OBJECT` macro.  You can verify this with certainty using [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/).  However, it's irrelevant, since `AddressBook` lasts the lifetime of the application.  Still, in a tutorial, it should have been freed, precisely to avoid raising concerns such as yours.

Comment: @MattPhillips But `AddressBook` only lasting the lifetime of the application doesn't influence `dialog`, does it? It would, if it had been created on the stack, but not in this case here...

Comment: The point is, the `AddressBook` instance is only destroyed when the application terminates, at which point all memory associated with it, including `dialog`, is freed.  So a memory leak is avoided, but in a stylistically poor and unscalable way.

Comment: As far as I'm concerned, the member should be declared as follows: `FindDialog dialog`. Then you don't need to explicitly allocate nor construct it, and it cannot leak. There's no good reason to use a pointer here at all.

Comment: It's also possible that the `FindDialog` frees itself when one close the (modal?) dialog window...

Comment: @Massa: That's certainly possible, but there perhaps should be a comment to that effect. The use of a pointer is still an unecessary complication.

Comment: Agreed! And even if the dialog frees itself, the pointer will dangle...

Comment: @Massa: not with QPointer, no.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no excuse for this, and it eventually has more issues than you just bring up, namely:

- It is not managed as you say.
- It does not use the conventional new Foo() syntax.
- It is not done in the constructor's initializer list.

The OS will probably free this up once the application quits, but still, I always speak up against such issues, anyhow, especially in example projects. The appropriate fix would be to use either a stack object instead of the heap object or `QPointer` in my opinion.

See the following post for details in case the latter:

[How to crash (almost) every Qt/KDE Application and how to fix](http://blogs.kde.org/2009/03/26/how-crash-almost-every-qtkde-application-and-how-fix-it-0)

This should be reported and fixed upstream; good catch!

I have just submitted a change to Gerrit about this [in here](https://codereview.qt-project.org/#change,83808).

Comment: Thanks for the info and the link to the blog-entry.. very interesting! I just posted on the qt-project.org-Forum suggesting to fix this.

Comment: Additional note about `new Foo` vs `new Foo()` syntax bullet point: since `Dialog` is a *non-POD type*, they do exactly same thing for it, but using `()` would still be good practice. More about it for example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/620402/1717300).

Comment: @hyde: Even non-POD types fall into the [non-initialized vs. default/value initialized difference](http://stackoverflow.com/a/620402/2682142) with C++03 and on. They were similarly uninitialized in C++98, so it will also depend on the standard variant. But as the update writes, there is a change submitted now to Gerrit which makes the object stack rather than heap.